# Does unsubscribing from observables make your application faster?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I was reading this guide on increasing speed in code with RXJS : https://blog.bitsrc.io/rxjs-patterns-efficiency-and-performance-10bbf272c3fc

In the guide, they never explicitly say that unsubscribing from an observable will decrease latency in your application. Is this true?

Comment: What are our assumptions? Is the observable idle and isn't receiving any events?

Comment: No, unsubscribing from an observable does not decrease latency. If anything, it will improve performance, because it doesn't trigger additional subscribers.

Comment: Unsubscribing could not be generalized to improving app latency. However one could say unsubscribing observables that aren't needed anymore _might_ not contribute to app latency.